# Not able to query my sqlite database

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

Below is my code, I'm attempting to retrieve data from an sqlite database with airport city names query from a user entered text field and retrieve the ICAO identifier to be presented in a label.  It seems the db is loading but it will not query when I select the IBAction button.  I think there might be something wrong with my query statement or my database, although I can't list that on here.  Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

The Last error I received is: database3[30351:c07] -[ViewController searchICAO:] 1st SQL error 'library routine called out of sequence' (21)

```
-(NSString*)filePath {
    NSArray*paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydatabase.sqlite"];
}

//open database
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [self openDB];
}


-(void)openDB {

    if(sqlite3_open([[self filePath]UTF8String], &airportDB) !=SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(airportDB);
        NSAssert(0, @"Databese failed to open");
        status.text = @"Database Failed to Open";
    }
    else if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath]UTF8String], &airportDB) ==SQLITE_OK) {//this line not really needed but was trying everything
        NSLog(@"database opened");          //test
        status.text = @"Database Opened";  //test
    }
}

- (IBAction)searchICAO:(id)sender
{
    //[self.delegate detailViewControllerDidFinish:self]; //for later use


    //Get airport name from the text field user enters
    NSString*sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM airports WHERE city=\"%@\"", [searchDB text]];

    const char *query_stmt = [sql UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSLog(@"%s 1st SQL error '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(airportDB), sqlite3_errcode(airportDB));  //Error Test
```

This is where I seem to be having problems at...

```
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(airportDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {// Problem is from here, can't get past this point

        NSLog(@"%s 2nd SQL error '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(airportDB), sqlite3_errcode(airportDB));  //Error Test

        if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

            status.text = @"";  //Clear the status line

            NSString *returnICAO = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            status.text = returnICAO;  //Insert Airport ICAO letters from the database table 

        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        [super viewDidLoad];
    }
    sqlite3_close(airportDB);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing exactly what is going wrong, but I would offer that, unless you have a specific objective that cannot be met by using third-party code, you should consider using FMDB https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb - assuming that you need to go directly to SQLite. I have used it quite a bit and had good success with it.

It's a little strange to be "closing" the DB and calling [super viewDidLoad] from searchICAO:. Was this deliberate? It seems like this might be the source of your problem? On the second query, the DB will be closed?

Comment: The [super viewDidLoad] was a mistake and was put in the proper place, but either way, it was not the problem.  I noticed it after I posted.  Thanks for your response, I will check out FMDB and see what I can come up with.